# How to make Sublime Text 2 use Cygwin instead of cmd?

Tags: grep, cygwin, cmd, sublimetext2

I would like to use [this plugin](https://github.com/technocoreai/SublimeExternalCommand) to, for example, `grep` selected text, so I need Sublime to use Cygwin instead of `cmd` for that.

Any way to do that via Sublime Text 2 settings?

Answer (score 2):

One option may be to point cmd prompt to all the binaries that cygwin has access to. I used cmd prompt as my 'terminal' by editing my PATH to include the binaries that cygwin includes.

if you're in windows 7 you can:
1) right click on computer, select properties
2) click on 'advanced system settings' on the pane on the left
3) click on 'enviornment variables' in the bottom right
4) depending on if you want this to be system wide or for your user only, edit the variable 'path' to have the path to your cygwin binaries. This will look something like adding the following text to the end of the path variable: ";c:\cygwin\bin"

now you can use cmd prompt to do most of the stuff cygwin allows you to do, such as use ls, mkdir, grep, etc.

Comment: I don't like this option because Windows "cmd" terminal is pretty silly by itself (consider it's autocompletion, for example).